# implementing registry by class type in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm pretty new to scala and i wonder how can i convert this simple Java reflection code representing a type based registry into scala:

```
public static interface IType {

}


public static interface IParser {

    public IType parse(byte[] msg);
}


public class Registry {
    private Map<Class<? extends IType>, Class<? extends IParser>> registry = new HashMap<Class<? extends IType>, Class<? extends IParser>>()
        {{
             // Init with types and parsers
        }};

    // Initiate new parser for the specified type
    public IParser getParser(Class<? extends IType> type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return registry.get(type).newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import scala.collection.mutable

  trait IType

  trait IParser {
    def parse(msg: Array[Byte]): IType
  }

  class Registry {
    private val registry = mutable.HashMap.empty[Class[T] forSome {type T <: IType}, Class[Z] forSome {type Z <: IParser}]

    def getParser(cl: Class[T] forSome {type T <: IType}) = {
      registry(cl).newInstance()
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

as [Kolmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098230/kolmar) mentioned in comments `Registry` class can be rewritten to:

```
  class Registry {
    private val registry = mutable.HashMap.empty[Class[_ <: IType], Class[_ <: IParser]]

    def getParser(cl: Class[_ <: IType]) = {
      registry(cl).newInstance()
    }

    def getParserT[T <: IType : ClassTag]: IParser = 
      getParser(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[IType]))
  }
```

with very convenient method  `def getParserT[T <: IType : ClassTag]: IParser` requires only type parameter where you have to pass a type that you want to instantiate.

Comment: Would there be any problem declaring types like `Class[_ <: IType]` instead of the `forSome` incantation?

Comment: you can't do that when you pass type parameters

Comment: @Kolmar, it will not compile

Comment: When you pass type parameters where? Because your snippet with this change obviously does compile, and you can even add a method like `def getParserT[T <: IType : ClassTag]: IParser = getParser(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[IType]))` to class `Registry`, and call it like `class IntT extends IType { /*...*/ }; new Registry().getParserT[IntT]`

Comment: my solution without  class type parameters and method type parameters - the same as your java code. getParserT[T <: IType : ClassTag] this code is not a direct convertion of your java code. Of course if you use method type params it can be clearer and without forSome.

Comment: First of all I'm not the OP, and I meant something like this snippet which doesn't use `forSome`: https://gist.github.com/kolmar/de1b70292c6dc0fd963f  You can get functions from the registry with either method: passing a type parameter or passing a `Class[_ <: IType]` argument.

Comment: Sorry I think it was OP) You are right, I misunderstood you about `Class[_ <: IType]`, if I'm not mistaken it's a syntactic sugar for `forSome` . Everything becomes clear from example. I like your solution with `ClassTag`.